Reducing length with a loop
I have a class which has a series of loops inside of it. Each loop uses a pandas.dataframe to add data to a new list that can be called as an instance attribute.
data = [player_stats, captured_creatures, item_list, moveset, opponents_stats, player_inventory]

class Battle():
    def __init__(self,data):

        stuff,stuff1,stuff2,stuff3,stuff4,stuff5 = [], [], [], [], [], []

        for t in data.player_stats.loc[0, :]:
            stuff.append(t)
        for t in data.captured_creatures.loc[0, :]:
            stuff1.append(t)
        for t in data.item_list.loc[0, :]:
            stuff2.append(t)
        for t in data.moveset.loc[0, :]:
            stuff3.append(t)
        for t in data.opponents_stats.loc[0, :]:
            stuff4.append(t)
        for t in data.player_inventory.loc[0, :]:
            stuff5.append(t)

        self.stuff = stuff
        self.stuff1 = stuff1
        self.stuff2 = stuff2
        self.stuff3 = stuff3
        self.stuff4 = stuff4
        self.stuff5 = stuff5


Is there a way that I can reduce the repetition in this? I know I can get the instance names using:
instances = [attr for attr in dir(data)][-6:]

I am unsure how to use that information to create a nested loop.
I hope this is clear.

What are player_stats, captured_creatures, etc.? DataFrames? How can data.player_stats give a value if data is a list? If not a list, then what is data?

Do you really need those loops? Why not just self.stuff = list(data.player_stats.loc[0])

The structures don't make sense to me. Why is it you're always doing .loc[0, :]?

If you do stuff, stuff1, ... , stuff5`, either you should be using a list or descriptive names.

I am not sure if your data are independent pandas dataframes so data would be a pandas df array. Therefore you can just summarize with the setattr method. Here an example:
# Sample data setup
player_stats = pd.DataFrame({
    'HP': [100],
    'Attack': [50],
    'Defense': [40]
})

captured_creatures = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Dragon'],
    'Level': [10],
    'Type': ['Fire']
})

item_list = pd.DataFrame({
    'Item': ['Potion', 'Elixir'],
    'Quantity': [3, 1]
})

moveset = pd.DataFrame({
    'Move': ['Fireball', 'Slash'],
    'Power': [40, 30]
})

opponents_stats = pd.DataFrame({
    'HP': [120],
    'Attack': [60],
    'Defense': [45]
})

player_inventory = pd.DataFrame({
    'Gold': [500],
    'Keys': [2],
    'Potions': [1]
})

# Combine the data into a list
data = [player_stats, captured_creatures, item_list, moveset, opponents_stats, player_inventory]
fields = ['player_stats', 'captured_creatures', 'item_list', 'moveset', 'opponents_stats', 'player_inventory']

# Define the Battle class
class Battle():
    def __init__(self, data):
        for name, df in zip(fields, data):
            setattr(self, f"{name}", df.loc[0].tolist())

# Instantiate a Battle
battle = Battle(data)

# Display the results
print("Player Stats:", battle.player_stats)
print("Captured Creatures:", battle.captured_creatures)
print("Item List:", battle.item_list)
print("Moveset:", battle.moveset)
print("Opponents Stats:", battle.opponents_stats)
print("Player Inventory:", battle.player_inventory)

Hope it helps!
